WinUI3 binding UI elements - can UI auto-update from changed viewModel params?
I inherited a WinUI3 app, it uses a view/viewModel paradigm, and the members of the viewModel  are Observable(s). I need to change one of viewModel's members (fields) directly, and want that change to show up in the UI. For example a slider value, or a checkbox. I have no idea where to start on this, but so far, no luck.
I have more info: First off, the app has different pages. But this problem is on the showing page, not a hidden and as yet unloaded page. Second, I get the MVVM model, for the most part. Made a sample app and changing the modelview's property does end up with the UI changing. A bit confused on the oneway vs twoway thing, but oh well. Seems to me that even with the XAML set to oneway, it worked how I expected it to.
The place it doesn't work is this app I inherited. Seems to be correctly using ObservableObject and ObservableProperty, but when I set the modelView's checkbox param, it doesn't show up in the UI. I am currently trying to trace it back and figure out where it's broken, but it seems to eventually dive into system code that obscures how and when this should be reflected in the UI.

There are several ways to implement MVVM. Can you add a minimal reproducible code in your question?

Windows data binding overview https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/data-binding/data-binding-overview

Not looking to read an article about data binding. Know all about how to get UI's changed to bind to viewModel vars. But changing the viewModel variable directly and have it affect the UI is different. and not explained anywhere very well.

If you know everything you shouldn't come here and ask questions, or maybe have to explain yourself a bit more, as "changing the viewModel variable directly and have it affect the UI" seems exactly what databinding is about (and in this case especially INotifyPropertyChanged).

anybody else want to help explain besides Simon? Getting the UI to update the viewModel's values, I get it. Changing viewModel's field's values and getting the UI to update, a mystery.

I suggest you could refer to the Doc:Windows data binding in depth:you can choose to "observe" the values and to update the UI when they change. You need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Ah, none of the comments were on track. I figured out what the problem was:
The Views and ViewModels were being added by AddTransient() in the Services stuff. This makes it so they're only valid when that page is current. When the page goes away, the pointer is tossed. When the page is re-shown, the viewModel is created again. This required that the page get deserialized upon creation.
Thus, when a page wasn't showing, and I would get a viewModel (for a view not showing) and set its property, then switch to the view, it would re-create the view and viewModel. My changed value wouldn't show.
The solution was to change it to AddSingleton().
        ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        // Default Activation Handler
        services.AddTransient<ActivationHandler<LaunchActivatedEventArgs>, DefaultActivationHandler>();

        // Other Activation Handlers

        // Services
        services.AddTransient<INavigationViewService, NavigationViewService>();

        services.AddSingleton<IActivationService, ActivationService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IPageService, PageService>();
        services.AddSingleton<INavigationService, NavigationService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IShellConnectionService, ShellConnectionService>();

        // Core Services
        services.AddSingleton<IFileService, FileService>();

        // Views and ViewModels
        // make the viewModels (at least!) into Singletons
        // so their values don't go away when the page isn't being shown.
        // Sure this keeps them "in memory", but we're not an Azure Excel Database, we can handle it.
        services.AddSingleton<BaseViewModelForPage>();
        services.AddSingleton<DisplayViewModel>();
        services.AddSingleton<DisplayPage>();
        services.AddSingleton<EnvironmentViewModel>();
        services.AddSingleton<EnvironmentPage>();
        services.AddTransient<ShellPage>();
        services.AddTransient<ShellViewModel>();
        services.AddSingleton<WorkspaceViewModel>();
        services.AddSingleton<WorkspacePage>();
        services.AddSingleton<VolumetricAppsViewModel>();
        services.AddSingleton<VolumetricAppsPage>();
        services.AddSingleton<DeveloperViewModel>();
        services.AddSingleton<DeveloperPage>();
        services.AddTransient<SystemViewModel>();
        services.AddTransient<SystemPage>();
        services.AddSingleton<VirtualCameraViewModel>();
        services.AddSingleton<VirtualCameraPage>();
        services.AddTransient<AboutPage>();
        services.AddTransient<AboutViewModel>();
    }).
    Build();

